# How can I fix a HTTP CORS error while deploying full stack project to Vercel?

Tags: node.js, vercel

I am trying to deploy a full stack app to Vercel, I have both the front end and back end working which have been uploaded as separate projects based on the folder structure of the project. While trying to make requests from the front end I run into CORS errors.

By adding the code below I seem to have cleaned up the header errors, but this is now giving me a HTTP error. What is causing this, and is there something that needs adding to the below vercel.json file?

The error I am receiving is:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at " " from origin " " has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status`

My vercel.json file is:

```
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "./client/src/index.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 0):

try with below:

```
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "./index.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No luck, still receiving the same error.

Comment: can you attach folder structure screenshot

Comment: I have the server and back end in the root folder and the front end in a subfolder, added a screenshot to the question